# How to compute (co)homology group of the Eilenberg-Maclane space $K(\pi,1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

It is well-known that the homology group and cohomology group of the Eilenberg-Maclane space $K(\pi,1)$ are:

> $$H_n(K(\pi,1))=\mathrm{Tor}^{\mathbf{Z}\pi}_n(\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{Z}),\quad H^n(K(\pi,1))=\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathbf{Z}\pi}^n(\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{Z})$$

I am trying to prove this and I want to avoid using the spectral sequence since this is an exercise on Davis-Kirk's [book](http://www.indiana.edu/~lniat/m621notessecondedition.pdf) before the spectral sequence part.

There is an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523008/isomorphism-involving-eilenberg-maclane-space-tors), using some theorem of derived functors. I like that proof. But I was wondering if there is any topological proof? Since we have the fibration (especially, universal covering), we can consider the local coefficient system.

On the other hand, when we use a $\mathbf{Z}\pi$-resolution to compute $\mathrm{Tor}$, we compute the homology of a complex tensored with $\mathbf{Z}$, which would hopefully coincide with the local coefficient system. Does this work? How can I continue?

There is a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530984/homology-of-eilenberg-maclane-k-pi-1-in-terms-of-group-homology-and-tor) on MSE. Feel free to close this question if you would like to answer there.

Also, I would like to know other approaches to proof the above result. Any hints, references or answers are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to prove this for $\mathbf{Z}$ : the local coefficient system is constant.

But then the proof is easier, for instance by considering a cell-structure on $K(\pi,1)$: take $E$ a universal covering space of your $K(\pi,1)$, and give it a cell-structure induced by the one on $K(\pi,1)$; that makes it into a free $\pi$-complex.

Then $C_*(E)$ (the cellular complex) is a chain complex of free $\pi$-modules; and if you look at what the cells in $E$ look like, it's pretty clear that $\hom_\pi(C_n(E), \mathbf{Z}) \simeq \hom(C_n(K(\pi,1)), \mathbf{Z})$ and similarly $C_n(E)\otimes_\pi \mathbf{Z} \simeq C_n(K(\pi,1))$, with maps induced by the covering map (so they must have the right differential).

You thus immediately get the result. If you have a nontrivial coefficient module, it's a bit trickier.